# undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, firebase

I'm trying to loop through a fileList in order to perform a delete query. First i fetched data from table "files" in database where attribute `"postnumber"=user` input. Then it is saved into the "`fileList:Files[]`". Then a loop through this fileList in order to perform a delete query. but it keeps saying that

> "ERROR TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property
>   Symbol(Symbol.iterator))". See this image =>

[image: error.jpg]

**forum-admin-list.component.ts**

```
import { FileService } from 'src/app/shared/file.service';
import { Files } from 'src/app/shared/files.model';
export class ForumAdminListComponent {
fileList:Files[];
onDelete(pNo:string){ 
        this.fservice.getPost(pNo).subscribe(actionArray => {
          this.fileList = actionArray.map(item => {
            return {
              id: item.payload.doc.id,
              ...item.payload.doc.data()
            } as Files;
          })
        });
        for(let i of this.fileList){
          this.storage.storage.refFromURL(i.path).delete();
          this.firestore.doc("files/"+i.id).delete();
        }
  }
}
```

**files.model.ts**

```
export class Files {
    id:string;
    pNo:string;
    downloadURL:string;
    path:string;
}
```

**file.service.ts**

```
export class FileService {
    formData: Files; 
    constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) { }

    getPost(userRef){
      return this.firestore.collection('files',ref=>ref.where('pNo','==',userRef)).snapshotChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're looping through the `fileList` outside the subscribe(), meaning it won't actually wait for the Observable to be resolved. Try to loop inside your subscribe().  Also you might wanna mark the result of the subscription `as Files[]` instead of `as File`.

Answer (score 0):

You're looping through the `fileList` outside the `subscribe()`, meaning it won't actually wait for the Observable to be resolved. Try to loop inside your `subscribe()`.

```
onDelete(pNo:string){ 
  this.fservice.getPost(pNo).subscribe(actionArray => {
    this.fileList = actionArray.map(item => {
      return {
        id: item.payload.doc.id,
        ...item.payload.doc.data()
      } as Files[];

      for(let i of this.fileList){
        this.storage.storage.refFromURL(i.path).delete();
        this.firestore.doc("files/"+i.id).delete();
      }
    })
  });
}
```

Also you might wanna mark the result of the subscription `as Files[]` instead of `as File`

Comment: It says that "i" is not defined.

Comment: can you check if  `this.fileList` isn't undefined after you give it its value? maybe your `subscribe()` response is empty or your logic in the `map()` is faulty, leaving the list undefined